# Problems upgrading React Native from 0.66.5 to 0.71.0: > Task :app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

Tags: react-native, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, updating

I'm facing some problems doing the update of ReactNative [from 0.66.5 to 0.71.0](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.66.5&to=0.71.0). Well, you need to solve some issues that I did little by little but now I am stuck with one related to this Gradle task, that I am not able to solve.

`> Task :app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED`

```
Execution optimizations have been disabled for task ':app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets' to ensure correctness due to the following reasons:
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '<whatever>/app/build/generated/res/react/release'. Reason: Task ':app:lintVitalAnalyzeRelease' uses this output of task ':app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
```

I think the key is in
`Reason: Task ':app:lintVitalAnalyzeRelease' uses this output of task ':app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency` but I am not being able to find the solution to it.

The fail summary:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.

> Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I think it is related to Hermes, seeing the trace:

```
at com.facebook.react.tasks.BundleHermesCTask.runCommand(BundleHermesCTask.kt:129)
        at com.facebook.react.tasks.BundleHermesCTask.run(BundleHermesCTask.kt:89)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, in our structure of subprojects, we needed to have `react-native` and `react` in the root folder as dependencies installed to be able to run all phases of the build correctly.

```
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.1"
  }
  ...
```